# The JScrollPane content doesn't refesh while scrolling

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm creating a simple gui of options that containing a JScrollPanel.

The problem is when I'm scrolling all the content of the JPanel inside my JScrollPanel doesn't refresh like that :
[Bad Refresh Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goHUb.png)

Another issues is that not all my text fields are well painted and the combobox fields are behind the first text field.

Here my code :

- OptionsPanel.java the source of the problem

  ```
  package scroll;

  import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.event.TextEvent;
  import java.awt.event.TextListener;

  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

  import scroll.NavigationButtons.Navigation;

  public class OptionsPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, TextListener {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 3800714599366218432L;

      private NavigationButtons navBtn;

      private ChangeOptionCB language;

      private ChangeOptionTF option1;

      private ChangeOptionTF option2;

      private ChangeOptionTF option3;

      private ChangeOptionTF option4;

      private ChangeOptionTF option5;

      private ChangeOptionTF option6;

      private ChangeOptionTF option7;

      private JScrollPane scrollPane;

      public OptionsPanel() {
          super();

          GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
          setLayout(layout);

          GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();

          JPanel optionsPanel = new JPanel();
          GridBagLayout l = new GridBagLayout();
          GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

          optionsPanel.setLayout(l);



          String[] langues = {"en", "fr", "es"};
          language = new ChangeOptionCB("Languages", langues);
          language.addTextListener(this);
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 0;
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
          c.weightx = 1;
          c.weighty = 0.1;
          optionsPanel.add(language, c);

          option1 = new ChangeOptionTF("option 1");
          option1.addTextListener(this);
          option1.setText("option 1");
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 1;
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
          c.weightx = 1;
          c.weighty = 0.1;
          optionsPanel.add(option1, c);

          option2 = new ChangeOptionTF("option 2");
          option2.addTextListener(this);
          option2.setText("option 2");
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 2;
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
          c.weightx = 1;
          c.weighty = 0.1;
          optionsPanel.add(option2, c);

          option3 = new ChangeOptionTF("option 3");
          option3.addTextListener(this);
          option3.setText("option 3");
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 3;
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
          c.weightx = 1;
          c.weighty = 0.1;
          optionsPanel.add(option3, c);

          option4 = new ChangeOptionTF("option 4");
          option4.addTextListener(this);
          option4.setText("option 4");
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 4;
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
          c.weightx = 1;
          c.weighty = 0.1;
          optionsPanel.add(option4, c);

          option5 = new ChangeOptionTF("option 5");
          option5.addTextListener(this);
          option5.setText("option 5");
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 5;
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
          c.weightx = 1;
          c.weighty = 0.1;
          optionsPanel.add(option5, c);

          option6 = new ChangeOptionTF("option 6");
          option6.addTextListener(this);
          option6.setText("option 6");
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 6;
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
          c.weightx = 1;
          c.weighty = 0.1;
          optionsPanel.add(option6, c);

          option7 = new ChangeOptionTF("option 7");
          option7.addTextListener(this);
          option7.setText("option 7");
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 7;
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
          c.weightx = 1;
          c.weighty = 0.1;
          optionsPanel.add(option7, c);

          scrollPane = new JScrollPane(optionsPanel);

          constraint.gridx = 0;
          constraint.gridy = 0;
          constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
          constraint.weightx = 1;
          constraint.weighty = 1;
          add(scrollPane, constraint);

          navBtn = new NavigationButtons(NavigationButtons.EXIT);
          navBtn.addActionListener(this);
          constraint.gridx = 0;
          constraint.gridy = 1;
          constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          constraint.weightx = 1;
          constraint.weighty = 0.25;
          add(navBtn, constraint);

      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          if (navBtn == ae.getSource()) {
              int id = ae.getID();
              if (Navigation.EXIT.getId() == id) {
                  System.out.println("Get out !!");
              } 
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void textValueChanged(TextEvent te) {
          if (language == te.getSource()) {
              System.out.println("The option as changed : "+language.getOption());
          }
          if (option1 == te.getSource()) {
              System.out.println("The option as changed : "+option1.getNewText());
          }
          if (option2 == te.getSource()) {
              System.out.println("The option as changed : "+option2.getNewText());
          }
          if (option3 == te.getSource()) {
              System.out.println("The option as changed : "+option3.getNewText());
          }
          if (option4 == te.getSource()) {
              System.out.println("The option as changed : "+option4.getNewText());
          }
          if (option5 == te.getSource()) {
              System.out.println("The option as changed : "+option5.getNewText());
          }
          if (option6 == te.getSource()) {
              System.out.println("The option as changed : "+option6.getNewText());
          }
          if (option7 == te.getSource()) {
              System.out.println("The option as changed : "+option7.getNewText());
          }
          scrollPane.revalidate();
          scrollPane.repaint();
      }

  }
  ```
- The Main Class

  ```
  package scroll;

  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;

  public class ScrollTest {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          JFrame frame = new JFrame();

          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.setResizable(false);
          frame.setContentPane(new OptionsPanel());
          frame.setTitle("Scrool Test");
          frame.pack();

          Dimension dimension = new Dimension(691, 263);
          frame.setSize(dimension);
          frame.setPreferredSize(dimension);
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
      }
  }
  ```
- The different stuff that you need :

  ```
  package scroll;

  import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.event.TextEvent;
  import java.awt.event.TextListener;

  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JComboBox;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
  import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

  public class ChangeOptionCB extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 3355314012553851743L;
      private JComboBox cb;
      private JButton saveBtn;

      private EventListenerList listeners;

      public ChangeOptionCB(String label, String[] list) {

          listeners = new EventListenerList();

          GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
          GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
          setLayout(layout);

          JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(label);
          jLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 0;
          c.weightx = 0.1;
          add(jLabel, c);

          cb = new JComboBox(list);
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          c.gridx = 1;
          c.gridy = 0;
          c.weightx = 0.8;
          add(cb, c);


          saveBtn = new JButton("Save");
          saveBtn.addActionListener(this);

          c.gridx = 2;
          c.gridy = 0;
          c.weightx = 0;
          c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
          add(saveBtn, c);

      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          if (ae.getSource() == saveBtn) {
              fireTextAsChange();
          }
      }

      public String getOption() {
          return (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
      }

      public void addTextListener(TextListener listener) {
          listeners.add(TextListener.class, listener);
      }

      public void removeActionListener(TextListener listener) {
          listeners.remove(TextListener.class, listener);
      }

      private void fireTextAsChange(){
          TextListener[] listenerList = (TextListener[])listeners.getListeners(TextListener.class);

          for(TextListener listener : listenerList){
              listener.textValueChanged(new TextEvent(this, 0));
          }
      }

  }

  package scroll;

  import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.TextField;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.event.TextEvent;
  import java.awt.event.TextListener;

  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

  public class ChangeOptionTF extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 3355314012553851743L;
      private TextField tf;
      private JButton saveBtn;

      private EventListenerList listeners;

      public ChangeOptionTF(String label) {

          listeners = new EventListenerList();

          GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
          GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
          setLayout(layout);

          JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(label);
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 0;
          c.weightx = 1;
          add(jLabel, c);

          tf = new TextField();
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 1;
          c.weightx = 0.5;
          add(tf, c);


          saveBtn = new JButton("Save");
          saveBtn.addActionListener(this);

          c.gridx = 2;
          c.gridy = 1;
          c.weightx = 0;
          c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
          add(saveBtn, c);

      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          if (ae.getSource() == saveBtn) {
              fireTextAsChange();
          }
      }

      public String getNewText() {
          return tf.getText();
      }

      public void addTextListener(TextListener listener) {
          listeners.add(TextListener.class, listener);
      }

      public void removeActionListener(TextListener listener) {
          listeners.remove(TextListener.class, listener);
      }

      private void fireTextAsChange(){
          TextListener[] listenerList = (TextListener[])listeners.getListeners(TextListener.class);

          for(TextListener listener : listenerList){
              listener.textValueChanged(new TextEvent(this, 0));
          }
      }

      public void setText(String text) {
          tf.setText(text);
      }

  }

  package scroll;

  import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

  public class NavigationButtons extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = -4844499317626526067L;

      public enum Navigation {
          NEXT(1), CANCEL(0), EXIT(-1);

          private int id;

          private Navigation(int id) {
              this.id = id;
          }

          public int getId() {
              return id;
          }
      }

      public static int NEXT_CANCEL = 0;
      public static int CANCEL = 1;
      public static int EXIT = 2;

      private JButton cancel;
      private JButton next;
      private JButton exit;

      private EventListenerList listeners;

      public NavigationButtons(int type) {

          listeners = new EventListenerList();

          GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
          GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
          setLayout(layout);

          if ((NEXT_CANCEL == type) || (CANCEL == type)) {
              cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
              cancel.addActionListener(this);

              c.gridwidth = 1;
              c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
              c.weightx = 1;
              add(cancel, c);
          }

          if (NEXT_CANCEL == type) {
              next = new JButton("Next");
              next.addActionListener(this);

              c.gridwidth = 1;
              c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
              c.weightx = 0;
              add(next, c);
          }

          if (EXIT == type) {
              exit = new JButton("Exit");
              exit.addActionListener(this);

              c.gridwidth = 1;
              c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
              c.weightx = 1;
              add(exit, c);
          }

      }

      public void setNextEnable(boolean b) {
          next.setEnabled(b);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          if (ae.getSource() == next) {
              fireActionPerformed(Navigation.NEXT);
          }
          if (ae.getSource() == cancel) {
              fireActionPerformed(Navigation.CANCEL);
          }
          if (ae.getSource() == exit) {
              fireActionPerformed(Navigation.EXIT);
          }
      }

      public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
          listeners.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
      }

      public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
          listeners.remove(ActionListener.class, listener);
      }

      public void fireActionPerformed(Navigation nav){
          ActionListener[] listenerList = (ActionListener[])listeners.getListeners(ActionListener.class);

          for(ActionListener listener : listenerList){
              listener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, nav.getId(), null));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

What is wrong in my code that make this ugly refresh ? I don't understand.

Maybe I need to implement a kind of listener that repaint my frame each time I scroll ?

The more strange things is, if I replace

```
add(scrollPane, constraint);
```

by

```
add(optionsPane, constraint);
```

the content get out well (at least in this example).

Thank's you

Julien

Comment: Hi @MonkeyJLuffy, welcome to StackOverflow!  For the quickest help, it helps if you can eliminate pieces of the code unrelated to the problem your experiencing (for example the ActionListeners).  Am I correct in saying the problem is that after you scroll, part of the ComboBox dropdown gets hidden behind the first TextField?

Comment: Could not reproduce your first issue using the provided code.  Can reproduce the second issue.

Comment: @NickRippe Hi Nick, thanks to have a look at my problem. I know that i need to remove lot off stuff, but in that case, the stuff was the problem :/. Merci. Julien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is, you're using `java.awt.TextField` which is a heavy weight component inside a lighweight container.  This is just asking for issues, they tend not to play well together.

Instead, use a `javax.swing.JTextField`

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.TextEvent;
import java.awt.event.TextListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

public class ChangeOptionTF extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3355314012553851743L;
    private JTextField tf;
    private JButton saveBtn;

    private EventListenerList listeners;

    public ChangeOptionTF(String label) {

        listeners = new EventListenerList();

        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        setLayout(layout);

        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(label);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        add(jLabel, c);

        tf = new JTextField();
```

Comment: YES !! That it !! Thank's a lot. When I made it, I do not pay attention at this little detail. You help me. Have a nice day :)