# JTextField showing through JComboBox's dropdown after Scrolling

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

When a `JTextField` is in a `JScrollPanel`, if the panel has been scrolled, whenever the dropdown from a `JComboBox` is over the `JTextField`, the text field shows through the dropdown. [image: JTextField shows through JComboBox Dropdown]

This *only* happens after the content has been scrolled (not on startup of the application).

The main question is how can we fix this?
Bonus points if the answer:

- Is not a hack
- Explains why is it happening in the first place

**Things I've tried:**

- Moving the dropdown outside of the scrollpane (no change)
- Adding a repaint to any and every container I could find on scroll (no change)
- Different Layout managers for the content of the scrollpane (no change)

**Code Example:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextFieldShowsThrough{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createScrollDemo());
        frame.pack();
        // For demonstration purposes
        frame.setSize(frame.getWidth() + 100, frame.getHeight() - 100);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static JScrollPane createScrollDemo(){
        final Box optionsPanel = Box.createVerticalBox();
        optionsPanel.add(createDropDown());
        optionsPanel.add(createTextField("Option1"));
        optionsPanel.add(createTextField("Option2"));
        optionsPanel.add(createTextField("Option3"));
        optionsPanel.add(createTextField("Option4"));
        optionsPanel.add(createTextField("Option5"));
        optionsPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        JScrollPane result = new JScrollPane(optionsPanel);
        // Made attempts to fix here, but to no avail
        /*result.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                result.repaint();
            }
        });*/
        return result;
    }

    public static Box createDropDown(){
        Box b = Box.createVerticalBox();
        b.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        b.add(new JLabel("Language"));
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(new String[]{"en", "fr", "es"});
        combo.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 25));
        b.add(combo);
        return b;
    }

    public static Box createTextField(String label){
        Box mainBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        mainBox.setOpaque(true);
        mainBox.setBackground(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)));  // because fun

        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(label);
        jLabel.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        mainBox.add(jLabel);

        Box secondaryBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        secondaryBox.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 25));
        secondaryBox.add(tf);

        mainBox.add(secondaryBox);

        return mainBox;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're using a `java.awt.TextField`, which is heavy weight component, inside a light weight container.  The popup window used by the `JComboBox` can also be a light weight component.

AWT components don't play well with Swing components, they have z-ordering issues.

Change `TextField tf = new TextField();` to `JTextField tf = new JTextField();`

You should also avoid using `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` (see [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) for more details) and instead use layout constraints and sizing hints (like the `columns` property of the `JTextField`)

Comment: Funny how you can miss that little "J" when looking at someone else's code.  Easy fix, good answer.  Will accept as soon as able.

Comment: I assume you mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899843/the-jscrollpane-content-doesnt-refesh-while-scrolling/33904482#33904482) code?

Comment: :P  Yep - There were issues in the question (refresh stuff?) I couldn't reproduce, so I couldn't "fix" the question, but it did spark curiosity.